# Keep the pop up box showing up when redirecting back to the page

Tags: php, authentication

In all of my pages, I have a text as button which if only it is clicked then it will show the login form up in a pop-up div. This pop up div will be closed automatically if the page is reloaded by the user.

Now I have a function in config.php file as the config of the login. And if the login is failed, then in the bellow or at the bottom of the login form there will be a notification saying that "Login is Failed".

The problem is because this login form will only show up if the user click the "login" button in the page, so when it redirect back it doesn't automatically tell the user if he/she failed to login. The user will have to click the login button again to know if the login is failed.

Here is the line where the user will know if the login is failed:

```
 <p><?php if($_GET['result']=='failed'){echo 'invalid login';}?></p>
```

This is the complete code of the login box where the user have to click the login button to show up the pop up div of login form:

```
        <li>
            <a href = "javascript:void(0)"
               onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                         document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Login</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!--Black Overlay-->        
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay" onLoad="initDynamicOptionLists()"></div>

    <!--Pop Up Div-->       
    <div id="light" class="white_content">

    <div id="loginbox">
        <span id="login-form">Login</span>
            <form method="post" action="config-login.php">
                <table width="345" align="center" style="background:honeydew; vertical-align:top; margin:0px auto; border:solid medium yellowgreen;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="myimage">Email :</td>
                        <td width="196" style="padding-right:2px;"><input type="text" name="member_email" style="width:100%"/></td></tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="myimage">Password : </td>
                        <td style="padding-right:2px;"><input type="password" name="member_password" style="width:100%"/></td></tr>

                </table>

                    <div style="background:greenyellow; display:block; width:100%; overflow:hidden; margin:10px 0; padding:10px 0;">

                        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />

                        <p><?php 
                            if($_GET['result']=='failed'){
                            echo 'invalid login';
                            }?>
                        </p>

                        <input class="myimage" style="margin-right:10px; padding:0 10px; float:right;" type="submit" value="Login"/>

                        <span style="position: absolute; top: 11px; right:1px; color:white;" id="closeBlocked">
                            <a style="color:green; text-decoration:none; background:white; padding:10px;" 
                               href = "javascript:void(0)" 
                            onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
                                      document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"><b>X</b></a></span>
                    </div>
            </form>

    </div>

    </div>
    <!-- End of Pop Up Div-->
```

---

---

```
   <?php
   session_start();

   // include connection file
   include("configPDO.php");

  $member_email=$_POST['member_email']; 
  $member_password=$_POST['member_password']; 
  $return = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['return']);

  $STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE member_email = :member_email AND member_password = :member_password");

 $STM->bindParam(':member_email', $member_email);
 $STM->bindParam(':member_password', $member_password);

 $STM->execute();

 $count = $STM->rowCount();

 $row  = $STM -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 if ( $count == 1 )  {
     session_start();
     $_SESSION['login_id'] = $row['member_id'];
     $_SESSION['member_name'] = $row['member_name']; // added
     $_SESSION['member_email'] = $row['member_email']; // added
            //echo 'SESSION =' .$_SESSION['myusername'];              
            //echo 'ROW =' .$row['myusername'];
            //var_dump($row);
    if ( $_SESSION['login_id'] != '' || $_SESSION['login_id'] > 0 ) { // edited
        header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);   
    } else { 
        header("location:index.php"."?result=failed");  
    }
}



 else 
 {
 header("location:index.php"."?result=failed");
 }
 $dbh = null;
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achive this with the help of your get variable

just add id to

```
    <a href = "javascript:void(0)"
           onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                     document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Login</a>

    like

    <a id="popmeup" href = "javascript:void(0)"
           onclick ="document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
                     document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">Login</a>

and put code at the end of document before end of body tag
    <?php 
    if($_GET['result']=='failed'){ ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById('popmeup').click();     
        </script>
    <?php   }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the box to reappear after the page is reloaded you could use the `window.onload` function to do so.

```
<?php if ( ! empty($_GET['result']) && $_GET['result'] == 'failed' ): ?>

<script>
    function showLogin() {
        document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
        document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
    }

    window.onload = showLogin;
</script>

<?php endif; ?>

<!--Black Overlay-->        
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay" onLoad="initDynamicOptionLists()"></div>

<!--Pop Up Div-->       
<div id="light" class="white_content">
```

**Edit:** Updated with script tags, oops.

Comment: I get an internal server error with your code. Do you missed something there?

Comment: `function showLogin() {
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';
}

window.onload = showLogin;` should be wrapped in `<script></script>` tags. @klaudia if you haven't done so.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash in the URL and check that with JavaScript. Added bonus: if the login form is below the fold of your user's browser window, it will automatically scroll there.

In your PHP file add `#loginbox` to your redirect: `header('Location: index.php?result=failed#loginbox');`.

Then, you can check if the login box should be shown with `window.location.hash`.

Something like this should work:

```
if (window.location.hash == 'loginbox') {
  document.getElementById('loginbox').style.display = 'block';
}
```

You could even use a pure CSS solution by using the `:target` pseudo-class to show the loginbox (this works in most modern browsers, I think).

Just adding this to your CSS file should work:

```
#loginbox:target {
  display:block;
}
```

**Edit:**

Just now saw that you probably hide the div with id `light` and not the lightbox one. You should obviously adapt the id according to the actual id you are hiding (via CSS `display:none;`, I guess).

Comment: If you already have JavaScript code, then put it there somewhere (inside a windows.onload or if you use JQuery, then in your $(document).ready() etc.). If not, then you should add it to the bottom of your page (right before the closing `</body>`, surrounded by a script tag (e.g. `<script type="text/javascript">if (window.location.hash == 'loginbox') { ... } </script>`).

Comment: I used the `header('Location: index.php?result=failed#loginbox');` in the config file but it makes my config stop and blank.

Comment: What do you mean with config file? The script you posted above? That line should replace the lines in your script that checks if the login was successful (the line `header("location:index.php"."?result=failed");` in the script you posted).